# Is it possible to mind control a soldier that has come under mind control from the enemy?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If one of my soldiers gets mind controlled, am I able to use my own mind control on him to turn him back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'll get a message saying the target is already under the effect of mind control. You'll have to wait for mind control to expire, stun/kill the ally or stun/kill the controller..

Comment: Can you mind control the controller?

Comment: @peakxu no, you can't.

Comment: @peakxu, you will receive message "Target is already Mind Controlling".